# Sort a numpy array like a table

Tags: python

I have a list

```
[[0, 3], [5, 1], [2, 1], [4, 5]]
```

which I have made into an array using numpy.array:

```
[[0 3]
 [5 1]
 [2 1]
 [4 5]]
```

How do I sort this like a table? In particular, I want to sort by the second column in ascending order and then resolve any ties by having the first column sorted in ascending order. Thus I desire:

```
[[2 1]
 [5 1]
 [0 3]
 [4 5]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort

Specifically in your case,

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0,3],[5,1],[2,1],[4,5]])
x[np.lexsort((x[:,0],x[:,1]))]
```

outputs

```
array([[2,1],[5,1],[0,3],[4,5]])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. I like this the best because it shows me that by replacing x[:,0] with x[::-1,0], I am able to reverse the direction of the second sorting (of the first column). Many thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numpy.lexsort()`:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[0, 3], [5, 1], [2, 1], [4, 5]])
>>> a[numpy.lexsort(a.T)]
array([[2, 1],
       [5, 1],
       [0, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this - slice out the bits of data you want, get the sort indices using argsort, then use the result of that to slice your original array:

```
a = np.array([[0, 3], [5, 1], [2, 1], [4, 5]])

subarray = a[:,1] # 3,1,1,5

indices = np.argsort(subarray) # Returns array([1,2,0,3])

result = a[indices]
```

Or, all in one go:

```
a[np.argsort(a[:,1])]
```

Comment: This doesn't sort the ties necessarily (1st column in ascending order).

Comment: True - lexsort looks like a better option here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort using a single column only (e.g., second column), you can do something like:

```
from operator import itemgetter
a = [[0, 3], [5, 1], [2, 1], [4, 5]]
a_sorted = sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1))
```

If there are more than one key, then use numpy.lexsort() as pointed out in the other answers.

Comment: Thank you, for my case `numpy.array(sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1)))` worked perfectly still being the most readable option.